# How to call a method on page load in jsp 2.0?

Tags: java, jsp

I have an index.jsp file and I want to call a method in Bean on load of this page.  How should I implement this part?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the javascript onLoad even handler or to call the method when the jsp is requested?

Comment: What I mean is to call a method that is on a bean..not calling javascript. Thnx

Comment: @Lindsey `I want to call a method in Bean on load of this page. `

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know onload in JSP. You need to make a request to jsp by writing some javascript.

onload event is in client side and you are wanting to do some server side stuff.

Answer (score 0):

These are totally two things. Do you want to do something when the HTML loaded or before the JSP is invoked.

case 1: No better ways than using jQuery ready event. It tries to wait until the page is loaded. But no one can assure this.
Example code:

```
$.ready(function(){
    /* do something. If it is an AJAX, use $.ajax(); */
});
```

case 2: You can either use a filter or just simply put the code on top of the JSP file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is really what you want. If you want to call a method on an object on server when your page is called, you have to ways to do it :

- a scriptlet at the beginning of the page, you can put the bean that you want to call is session or application scope
- do not call directly the jsp but create a servlet. Do all your java treatment in the servet, load beans in request attributes if you want to use them later in the jsp and forward to the jsp.

The latter solution avoid the scriptlet and is easier to write and to test.